# Catch ngRepeat init event

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I need to detect a moment, when `ngRepeat` appear, before data is ready.

I've tried to use `compile` (it fires once for ngRepeat), but still no luck, it fires after data is ready.

The goal is to set loading spinner on parent directive. And to remove it on data ready.

Guess I can use parent post link to search for directive in child, but it is not the angular way.

Here is the plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/5OY5ySZm5L6Ba5Vw17af?p=preview

```
    function testDirective(){
        return {
            compile: function compile(){
                console.log('on data ready too, but I want it to be fired on init');
                return {
                    pre: function(scope){

                        if(scope.$first){
                            console.log('first');
                        }

                        if(scope.$last){
                            console.log('last');
                        }
                    }
                };
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is not the angular way either. Add your code here or a plunker to get help.

Comment: ... plunker of what? Of ngRepeat usage? Ok.

Comment: @VassilisPits as good as done

Comment: @VassilisPits, btw, what do you mean by "Not the angular way either"?

Answer (score 0):

I would somply use `ng-show` directive like this :

```
<ul ng-controller="TestController as tc">
    <li ng-show='tc.items' ng-repeat="item in ::tc.items">{{::item}}</li>
    <div ng-show='!tc.items'>Loading...</div>
</ul>
```

Here is a working plunker. https://plnkr.co/edit/hOGlVZkmoMUyOOEskcnM?p=preview

If you need something less specific, i could do this as a wrapper directive.

Comment: But I still need scope vars.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. `priority: 1001` on my directive. Then compile fires before ngRepeat.

Here is a working plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/5OY5ySZm5L6Ba5Vw17af?p=preview